# Adding Regularization Gives Slower and Worse Performance

Tags: performance, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, regularized

When I added stronger regularization (e.g. L2 regularization parameter from 1 to 10, or dropout parameter from 0.75 to 0.5), it gave me slower and worse performance (e.g. 97-98% test accuracy in 3000-4000 iterations to only 94-95% test accuracy in 3000-4000 iterations). Is there maybe a reason for this occurring? I can confirm that everything is implemented correctly. Thank you!

Edit: I just want to note that my program has overfitting (about 1%), and it seems also that with and without dropout, the difference between training and test accuracy are about the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Underfitting might be the reason for the sharp decrease in accuracy. Use smaller values for l2 regularizaiton less than 1. Check for [0.01,0.03,0.1,0.3,0.9] and see.

Comment: Thank you for all your help, but unfortunately, the neural network is actually still overfitting. It is just that I really want to find a regularization technique since that is the only way I can get a test accuracy > 99%. I was just wondering if you maybe have some other regularization techniques I could try or some more reasons for why this is occurring? Thank you for everything!